# Should external javascript file start and end with <script> </script>?

Tags: javascript, external

I want to use jquery in my web application. Should I include it as a link in my external JavaScript file or inside my html file?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try that before asking?

Comment: Do you mean having `<script> /* my js */ </script>` inside a js file ?

Comment: This should clear it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script - See the examples bit

Comment: Yes. It's not self closing element. You need to close it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is asked without any re-search.

Comment: Pick a CDN, copy-pasta their code: https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/#jquery

Answer (score 1):

No. The way to include a javascript file is using `<script src="file.js"></script>`

The contents of ***file.js*** should not be surrounded with `<script>` tags as that is html code.

Answer (score 0):

Yea sorry i was mistaken, didn't think external javascript counts but apperantly it does.

```
<script src="myScript.js"> code in here </script>
```